# Count the free elements from a specific point in array

Tags: java

I am fresh to Java World and start to learn it. What I am going to do is counting the free elements from a specific point in an array. A free element is counted if the next moving element in horizontal or vertical direction from the moving point is not occupied.

Below are my codes:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] arrs= new char[11][15];
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                arrs[i][j] = '-';
            }
        }
        arrs[0][0] = '+';
        arrs[0][1] = '+';
        arrs[0][2] = '+';
        arrs[0][3] = '+';
        arrs[0][4] = '+';
        arrs[1][0] = '+';
        arrs[1][1] = 'P';
        arrs[1][4] = '+';
        arrs[2][0] = '+';
        arrs[2][1] = '+';
        arrs[2][2] = '+';
        arrs[2][4] = '+';
        arrs[3][3] = '+';
        arrs[3][4] = '+';

        Point point= new Point (1, 1);
        int result = 0;
        calculate(point, arrs, result);
        System.out.print(result);

    }

    private static void calculate(Point point, char[][] arrs, int result) {
        int x = point.getX();
        int y = point.getY();
        if (x >= 0 && x < 11 && y >= 0 && y < 13 && arrs[x][y + 1] == '-') {
            result = result + 1;
            arrs[x][y + 1] = 'o';
            calculate(new Point(x, y + 1), arrs, result);
        }
        if (x >= 0 && x < 11 && y > 0 && y < 14 && arrs[x][y - 1] == '-') {
            result = result + 1;
            arrs[x][y - 1] = 'o';
            calculate(new Point(x, y - 1), arrs, result);
        }
        if (x >= 0 && x < 10 && y >= 0 && y < 14 && arrs[x + 1][y] == '-') {
            result = result + 1;
            arrs[x + 1][y] = 'o';
            calculate(new Point(x + 1, y), arrs, result);
        }
        if (x > 0 && x < 11 && y >= 0 && y < 14 && arrs[x - 1][y] == '-') {
            result = result + 1;
            arrs[x - 1][y] = 'o';
            calculate(new Point(x - 1, y), arrs, result);
        }
    }
```

My idea is I will start to count at the point where P is located, here is my point(1,1). Then I will check if each of the next element on the right/left/bottom/top is moveable, if yes then I count and move the next calculation to this point and repeat the process.

Unfortunately I endup the with result 0. Can anyone help me where did I make a mistake here? Thank you very much in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple. You could use either **Depth-first search** or **Breadth-first search** with mark visited cells.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    char[][] arr = {
            { '+', '+', '+', '+', '+' },
            { '+', 'C', '-', '-', '+' },
            { '+', '+', '+', '-', '+' },
            { '-', '-', '-', '+', '+' },
    };

    System.out.println(new CountMovableSteps(arr).getAsInt()); // 3
}

public final class CountMovableSteps implements IntSupplier {
    private final char[][] board;
    private int x = -1;
    private int y = -1;

    public CountMovableSteps(char[][] board) {
        this.board = new char[board.length][];

        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            this.board[row] = new char[board[row].length];

            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                this.board[row][col] = board[row][col];

                if (board[row][col] == 'C') {
                    x = col;
                    y = row;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getAsInt() {
        return dfs(0, x, y);
    }

    private int dfs(int count, int row, int col) {
        if (row < 0 || row >= board.length || col < 0 || col >= board[row].length)
            return count;
        if (board[row][col] == '+' || board[row][col] == '*')
            return count;

        if (board[row][col] != 'C')
            count++;

        board[row][col] = '*';
        count = dfs(count, row, col + 1);
        count = dfs(count, row, col - 1);
        count = dfs(count, row + 1, col);
        count = dfs(count, row - 1, col);

        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Oleg, I will try it

Comment: @Joe I have modified the answer with more suitable solution.

Comment: Hi Joe, it worked perfectly! Only inside of the method finding x and y, it should be x = row; y = col and then working fine!. But thank you very much for your tips :D

Answer (score 1):

your int (result) was passed by value. When you assign a new value in you method calculate it will not change the value of the original result.

```
private static int calculate(Coordinate cCoordinate, char[][] board) {
    int x = cCoordinate.getX();
    int y = cCoordinate.getY();
    if (x >= 0 && x < 11 && y >= 0 && y < 13 && board[x][y + 1] == '-') {
        board[x][y + 1] = 'o';
        return calculate(new Coordinate(x, y + 1), board, result) + 1;
    }
    if (x >= 0 && x < 11 && y > 0 && y < 14 && board[x][y - 1] == '-') {
        board[x][y - 1] = 'o';
        return calculate(new Coordinate(x, y - 1), board, result) + 1;
    }
    if (x >= 0 && x < 10 && y >= 0 && y < 14 && board[x + 1][y] == '-') {
        board[x + 1][y] = 'o';
        return calculate(new Coordinate(x + 1, y), board, result) + 1;
    }
    if (x > 0 && x < 11 && y >= 0 && y < 14 && board[x - 1][y] == '-') {
        board[x - 1][y] = 'o';
        return calculate(new Coordinate(x - 1, y), board, result) + 1;
    }
}
```

Something like this should work. It will return the count. However the problem is a little bit more complex if you want to handle all the cases. But I think you should find the answer to the rest yourself.

Comment: `int result` isn't a reference it's a primitive value. Java is pass by value: it may access objects through references but it still passes those references by value, however, primitives are not object references, they are just values.

Comment: hi Mahieus, thank for your answer but it did not work, I tried but it still returned 0

Comment: Hi Joe, I only indicated the issue regarding problems with not knowing/being new to Java. The rest you could easily find by debugging the application. I would advise you to do so it will help you understand and you'll learn faster this way instead of copy pasting the full solutions. Good luck!